# Why doesn't it get the full source code?

Tags: java

```
private static String[] getUrlSource2(String site) throws IOException {
    List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
    URL url = new URL(site);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); //     Cast shouldn't fail
    HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
    String encoding = conn.getContentEncoding();
    InputStream inStr = null;


    if (encoding != null && encoding.equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
        inStr = new GZIPInputStream(conn.getInputStream());

    } else {
        inStr = conn.getInputStream();
    }

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStr,"UTF-8"));
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        myList.add(inputLine);
    in.close();

    String[] arr = myList.toArray(new String[myList.size()]);
    return arr;

    }
```

This is my getSource method, for some reason it just gives me part of the source code of a url page, I can't figure out why..
If yo could help, I would be deeply apreciatted.

For example if you run this:

```
public class Main  {

public static void main(String[] args){
    try {
        String [] A =getUrlSource2("https://www.google.pt/");

    for(int i=0;i<A.length;i++){
        System.out.print(String.valueOf(i)+"        ");
        System.out.println(A[i]);


    }

}catch(IOException e){

    }
}
```

You will get 5 lines of source code when you should get about 300/400

Comment: What part does it give you? What part is missing?

Comment: Need more information whats missing. Keep in mind that anything retrieved via AJAX requests will not be included.

Comment: I can't figure out a criteria for what is missing, some apparently random parts simply don't show up..

Comment: I've added a test 'Main' using google homa page

Comment: The snippet you shared works fine

Comment: How many line of source code did you get?

Comment: I tried and also got 5 lines of code. But it ends with `</script></div></body></html>`. There might be a difference between what you see on the browser and what your Java code produces. For example, the browser may automatically follow redirects and process other headers, etc. But your Java code will only fetch what is retrieved in one call to the page.